# Silver Light Chat

Tags: silverlight-5.0

I want to build a chat system in Silver Light(Video, Audio both).Though I have experience of Asp.Net in C# using Sql Server. Since I am new to Silver Light, so I need some basic guidance related to it. Some good references , Latest version of Silver Light , or anything that may be helpful for me.
I want to integrate this chat in my Asp.Net Web Application. Should I create a new Silver Light Application in the existing solution. Read different articles, have a confusion that using WCF is neccessary ? 
I need to accomplish the following : 
Text chat, video calling , voice calling, saving chat , popup on user request, blocking a user, group chat.

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a chat application, signalR is your best friend. Here is an article to get you started http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/619376/SignalR-with-Silverlight